# Как правильно выстроить работу с Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Всем привет, пишу телеграм бота и решил подключить Hibernate в проекте.
Подскажите как правильнее выстроить работу с хибернейтом, что бы не получать в каждом классе инстанс сессии, или по другому ни как?

Comment: Вопрос очень общий. Чтобы вам могли помочь, покажите, как сейчас инстанциируются классы (или по крайней мере как планируется это делать), в которых вам нужен доступ к сессии.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я создаю бота без применения спринга, по этому классы инстанциируются через new, по этому без доступа к сессии